# Can you underline directories in zsh with ls?

Tags: terminal, zsh, ls, bsd

I would like to underline directories when I do `ls`. Is this possible in a default Mac terminal and zsh? Or do I need something like iTerm2 + ohmyzsh. From what I found `LSCOLORS` doesn't support underline only bold.

Example: so Folder1 and Folder2 would be displayed with an underline
[image]

Comment: you don't need iTerm2 + omz. `LSCOLORS` support it. Use `04`, see [`Underlined`](https://gist.github.com/thomd/7667642)

Comment: Here is an example:
`LS_COLORS='rs=0:di=01;04;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=01;34:ow=01;34:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.zwc=02:*.DS_Store=02:';
export LS_COLORS`

Comment: And you need ls from [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/), you can install from Homebrew. And `alias ls='gls --l --color'`

Comment: @TianshuWang May I suggest that you create a proper answer out of the comments above?

Comment: @TianshuWang `LSCOLORS` and `LS_COLORS` are not the same. zsh uses `LSCOLORS` with a different [format](https://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/).

Comment: @Bn.F76 Thanks for the heads up, I hadn't noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need iTerm2 + omz.

I suggest to use GNU `ls` and `LS_COLORS`, you can install [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) (through homebrew) and `alias ls='gls --l --color'`.

Steps:

1. `brew install coreutils`
2. in `.zshrc` or `.bash_profile` put

`LS_COLORS='di=01;04'`
`alias ls='gls --l --color'`